# Android Bluetooth file transfer

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to implement file transfer through bluetooth and i am using the Bluetooth -chat example that comes with the android sdk.

When i try connecting two android phones, they seem to always say, the phones are paired but not connected. This is tedious as i have tried to connect with 3 different pairs of phones and all of them say the same thing.

Is it required for the devices to be rooted or something?? How can i connect two android phones through bluetooth.

Comment: Good luck. Bluetooth is very tricky on the Android. I implemented a bluetooth connection with a KDC200 (bluetooth barcode scanner) over SPP last year. It didn't like to work all the time and it was quite hard to find out if the device was still actually connected. Part of the problem was with the Android device unpairing the scanner. The app would then think the scanner is still connected and wait for input. What a headache!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This isn't strictly an answer, but I am yet unable to post comments.)

I've personally had good success with the Bluetooth Chat example code, and I've used it to create an application that interfaces with a Bluetooth/RS232 dongle to obtain lots of measurement data from a remote hardware device. I do confess, however, that I've only ever used the host Bluetooth code to initiate a connection to the Bluetooth SPP dongle; I've not attempted to connect to the slave code on another phone.

For reference, the two devices I've used my app on with success are my HTC Desire (2.2) and my Archos 101 (2.2). They are not rooted.

One thing that I think is worth me mentioning is that the Bluetooth Chat example appears to have a bug in the code where it accepts an array of received bytes out of the socket and presents them into the ListActivity. If lots of characters are sent from the remote device at anything much faster than typing speed, what is shown in the ListActivity on the phone shows the occasional character being corrupted. It's because (I think) the ArrayAdapter is still consuming bytes from that array to print them on the screen when the connected thread starts to fill that same array with even newer bytes. So, I had to fix that before I could use the Bluetooth Chat example code to reliably receive relatively large volumes of data from the external device.

On either the HTC Desire or Archos 101 I don't seem to have any problems with connection. I can happily have the Bluetooth connection exist reliably even over poor signal conditions (e.g. the remote device is upstairs in the house while I'm downstairs with the Android device) while my app happily polls measurement data reliably at a rate of about 250bytes a second.

Comment: Thanks @adorablepuppy and @Trev16v. Bluetooth in Android is weird, i have now graduated from not connected to on-off connected. Debugging the application does not seem to help either.(Throws up nothing).

Answer (score 1):

Generate UUID of your phone by using adb shell, sdptool browse command